# How can I export my symbology, "Style" from ArcGIS Pro for use in Leaflet (JSON)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, leaflet, arcgis-pro, symbology, software-recommendations

I am looking to export the symbology / style from ArcGIS Pro to use in Leaflet.  We have too many colors and regular changes to manually set the colors within Leaflet.

I understand there is not a simple way of doing it, but wondering if there is a conversion software or tool that can do this for me.

Comment: Is the data hosted as a feature service via AGOL or enterprise? How do you consume the data in leaflet?

Comment: For our application it has to be saved in a json format.

Comment: So what you would need is some kind of ESRI Style parser. You can follow this discussion here: https://github.com/geostyler/geostyler/issues/1204 - they tried to find a way to parse Esri style files. Unfortunately I don't think there is a generic way of doing it. If you would host the data as a servie you could use feature styling.

Comment: If you use the esri-leaflet plugin https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet and access your data as a service in your app you can use the service symbology plugin https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/renderers-plugin.html